# Failed to execute child process for a codelite code

Tags: c++, terminal, ubuntu-18.04, codelite

I've installed codelite IDE version 13.0.8, my laptop runs on ubuntu 18.04.3, compiling and building my first program seems to be error-free however when I attempt to run it the terminal window prompts the following error:

**There was an error creating the child process for this terminal

**Failed to execute child process “/bin/bash -f "/home/manel/.codelite/tmp/manel/codelite-exec.sh"” (No such file or directory)****

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: How are you attempting to run it?

Comment: I can't seem to understand the question, the problem is that whenever I click run on the IDE, the IDE doesn't run that code on the terminal, it displays that error.

Comment: Sounds like you havn't configured it properly. What have you tried?

Comment: Which terminal are you using? You can select a different one from `Settings->Preferences->Terminal`, try picking a different one and see if it works. Also try checking that the folder `/home/manel/.codelite/tmp/manel` does exist